# Unicode and the Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, python-unicode

If I want to enter unicode to my database via the admin how would I go about doing that?  If I want to enter 2^5 into the database to have it output on a template as a superscript can I do this via the admin?  I have tried just entering \u0034\u2075 but it does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Views

```
def recipes(request):
    recipe_list = Recipe.objects.all()
    ingredient_list = Ingredient.objects.all()
    context = {
        'recipe_list': recipe_list,
        'ingredient_list': ingredient_list,
    }
return render(request, "recipes/test.html", context)
```

Template

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ var }}</h1>
    {% for q in recipe_list %}
        <h1>{{ q }}</h1><br />
        {% for i in ingredient_list %}

            {{ i }}<br />

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

I have tried adding some unicode directly to the view and that worked fine.  I added var = u'\u0034\u2075' in the view function and passed it into the context dictionary and simply added a {{ var }} in the template and that worked fine but I can't seem to get it working pulling it from the database by adding it through the admin.

Comment: Have you tried directly pasting the Unicode value like (x³)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: What do you expect to be displayed by the rendered template, and what do you actually get? How is `Recipe` related to `Ingredient`? It seems strange to loop through the ingredients inside the recipe loop. That means you'll display *every* ingredient for every recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Entering the actual unicode characters (e.g. `4⁵`) into the admin should work. Django supports unicode everywhere, [as long as your database supports it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#creating-the-database).

Comment: Yeah I am using postgresql and the encoding is set to utf8 so it should support it but when I try and use the database to output into a template it just displays as \u0034\u2075.